# Dynamically pass data to component

Tags: angular, google-maps, ionic3, ionic-native

I am working with google-maps native and i am trying to pass the marker array data to an attached component but couldnt find any method that would work. Is there any possible way to pass the data in the following code:

```
markerCluster.on(GoogleMapsEvent.MARKER_CLICK).subscribe((params) => {

    let htmlInfoWindow = new HtmlInfoWindow();
    let marker: Marker = params[1];

    console.log(params[1]);

    if(this.compRef) this.compRef.destroy();

    const compFactory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(MapPopup);
    this.compRef = compFactory.create(this.injector);

    this.appRef.attachView(this.compRef.hostView);

    let frame: HTMLElement = document.createElement('div');
    frame.appendChild(this.compRef.location.nativeElement);

    htmlInfoWindow.setContent(frame, {
      width: "230px",
        height: "150px",
    });
    htmlInfoWindow.open(marker);

  });
```

And here is the array data that i would like to pass over so when i click a marker the appropriate info gets passwed to the component:

```
dummyData() {
return [
  {
    "position": {
      "lat": 46.0738144,
      "lng": 18.210416
    },
    "name": "Place 1",
    "rating": "4",
    "restaurantId": "2"
  },
  {
    "position": {
      "lat": 46.0733244,
      "lng": 18.210716
    },
    "name": "Place 2",
    "rating": "3",
    "restaurantId": "3"
  }
];
```

}

Any help would be much appreaciated!
Thanks, Trix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to component as an angular component, you can use the @Input() decorator and pass data to your component. In the component itself, it would be

```
@Input() passedData: any[];
```

and on the parent html

```
<custom-component [passedData]="dataToPass"> </custom-component>
```

and in your parent .ts,

```
let dataToPass = [
  {
    "position": {
      "lat": 46.0738144,
      "lng": 18.210416
    },
    "name": "Place 1",
    "rating": "4",
    "restaurantId": "2"
  },
  {
    "position": {
      "lat": 46.0733244,
      "lng": 18.210716
    },
    "name": "Place 2",
    "rating": "3",
    "restaurantId": "3"
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! That helped me out :)